# Does Carthage support having different versions of the same library together?

Tags: ios, carthage

Let's say I have

Library A dependent on 2 libraries.

```
LibraryA
-> LibraryB 0.0.2
-> LibraryC 0.0.2
```

And Library B depends on Library C as well, but with different version

```
LibraryB
-> LibraryC 0.0.1
```

When running Carthage for Library A, I expect the resolved outcome to be

```
LibraryA
-> LibraryB 0.0.2
-> -> LibraryC 0.0.1
-> LibraryC 0.0.2
```

so that I could have 2 versions of Library C independently.

But the actual result will be an error:

```
Could not pick a version for LibraryC, due to mutually incompatible requirements:
    == 0.0.2
    == 0.0.1
```

Can I achieve the result I want with Carthage?